# Why is the page number not in the footer of my page?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

When I use the below code, the page number on page 2 appears above the footer.  Why, and how do I put it in the footer? And what happened to the footer line on page 1?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[showframe,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[c]{Header}

\setlength\headheight{105pt}
\setlength\textheight{556pt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

Page 1 text

\newpage
\setlength\headheight{12pt}
\setlength\textheight{649pt}
\thispagestyle{plain}

Page 2 text


\end{document}
```

Comment: Better use package `geometry` to change the page layout mid-document. Concerning the `plain` pagestyle, please have a look at section 7 of the fancyhdr manual.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `\newgeometry` for changing the geometry in the middle of the document. \newgeometry also causes a pagebreak.
I also had to include the header and footer because geometry would count margins for the text and the header/foot would be inside the margins itself, maybe that's why your page numbering was getting plotted in the wrong height. Page 3 shows in plain style just for comparison. 
Compiled with TexWorks (pdfLaTeX), screenshot view in Adobe Reader 2015.

[image: Page 1 and 2 with different header size]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[showframe,footskip=.25in,includehead, includefoot,headheight=12pt,textheight=649pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[c]{Header}


\begin{document}
\newgeometry{showframe,footskip=.25in,includehead, includefoot,headheight=105pt,textheight=556pt}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

Page 1 text

\newpage
\restoregeometry % From this point on the document will use the definitions in the preamble
\thispagestyle{fancy}


Page 2 text

\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
Page 3 text


\end{document}
```

Comment: How about adding a screen shot? You should mention, that `\newgeometry` will cause a page break (which is intended here, of course)

Comment: That image is the actual screenshot, except for page 3. Will add about page break, thanks.